# Design Pattern for generic serialization interface

Tags: c++, serialization, design-patterns, interface

I have a library that manages a directed acyclic graph (DAG) of generic objects. The structure is somewhat along the lines of

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Node
{
    // depth first search visitor pattern along the lines of ...
    template <typename Visitor>
    void accept(Visitor& v) {
        v.visit(*this);
        for(auto& child: children) {
            child->accept(v);
        }
    }

    //...

protected:
    virtual ~Node(){}

private:
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Node>> children;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> parents;
};
```

I now want to allow users of the library to serialize a DAG/Node using their choice of serialization mechanism. That is, I want to leave it up to the user if they want to use boost::serialize, jsoncpp, yaml-cpp or whatever they like.

Currently I am struggling of finding an appropriate design pattern. The best I could think of is the following approach, but it makes me feel a bit uncomfortable:

Since a user might create several classes derived from `Node`, but `Node` only knows about its children/parents as pointers to `Node`, it makes sense to me to add a virtual `serialize` method to `Node` that the user of the library could override. But what would that method return? This really depends on the serialization library the user chooses, could be `YAML::Node` or `Json::Value`, ... I want the DAG library to be agnostic of this. I can't make a virtual function a template, but I could create another dummy class

```cpp
class Serialized
{
protected:
    virtual ~Serialized(){}
};
using PSerialized = std::unique_ptr<Serialized>;
```

and have the virtual `Node::serialize` method return a `PSerialized` intance. The user of the library could then derive from `Serialized` and `Node` and create a serialization visitor:

```cpp
struct MyYaml : public Serialized
{
    YAML::Node node;
};

template <typename T>
PSerialized serialize(T const& t){
    MyYaml x;
    // ....
}

template <typename T>
struct MyNode: public Node
{
    PSerialized serialize() const override
    {
         MyYaml root;
         return ::serialize(value);
         // the user could serialize adjacency information here by iterating over parents and/or children, or not, I don't care.
    }

    T value;
};

struct ToYamlVisitor
{
    void visit(Node& node) {
        auto s = node.serialize();
        auto y = static_cast<ToYaml const*>(s.get());
        //...
    }

    YAML::Node yaml;
};

YAML::Node serialize(MyNode const& node)
{
   ToYamlVisitor visitor;
   node.accept(visitor);
   return visitor.yaml;
}
```

This will (probably) work, but ...

- it's a bit complicated for the user
- the `Serialized` base class is empty which makes it feel like a design flaw
- The user needs to downcast the `Serialized` instance in `ToYamlVisitor`, which also sounds like a design flaw.

The last two points are related because I wouldn't know how to write an interface for `Serialized` that would not require extensive glue code for the different serialization libraries. Most libraries allow to stream the serialized objects to a file or `std::string` or `std::cout` etc. and I don't want to enforce these by creating e.g. a stream operator an interface function for each.

As an alternative, I could remove the `Serialized` base class and have `Node::serialize` return an `std::any`, but I don't think this would really be a much cleaner solution.

Now my question is: Is it a design flaw? What different choice do I have? Is there a design pattern for this kind of situation that I don't know about/couldn't make a connection to my use case?

Comment: Just use a generic intermediate representation like a [Boost.PropertyTree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) or something. Every node serializes itself to this representation and every serializer formats this representation accordingly. This also makes it super easy to roundtrip-test your (de)serializers.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about Boost.PropertyTree yet and it seems like a good solution here. It would still be a somewhat complicated interface, but at least we wouldn't have the empty base class and downcast issue anymore. I suppose it's just hard to make generic things easy :)